# Data missing after deploying to Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

In my web app's index.html, I created a bunch of data as such

```
  <script>
      var app = document.querySelector('#app');
      app.data = [
        {id: 0, consumed: 6, protein: 4, sodium: 87, calcium:.14, iron: .01},
        {id: 1, consumed: 2, protein: 4.3, sodium: 129, calcium:.08, iron: .01},
        {id: 2, consumed: 0, protein: 6, sodium: 337, calcium:.06, iron: .07},
        {id: 3, consumed: 0, protein: 4.3, sodium: 413, calcium:.03, iron: .08},
        {id: 4, consumed: 0 , protein: 3.9, sodium: 327, calcium:.07, iron: .16},
      ];

</script>
```

While deploying locally (i.e localhost), my app can access this set of data. However after deploying to Firebase, the data is not available to the deployed app. I verified this via Chromes developer tools (console).

May I know why this data is missing and how to fix it?

Comment: Running `firebase deploy` does not change any of the files. So it seems more likely that the file containing this script was not deployed at all. Can you confirm? If so: what is the path to the file from where you run `firebase deploy` and what is the config in your `firebase.json`?

Comment: Not enough data here to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks guys for responding.  I'm using the polymer-starter-kit and added that script in the main index.html file. Looking at it again, maybe the gulp process did something to it but I'm not sure where at the moment.